# Finding the proper pushout vector between two AABB boxes, knowing the velocity

Tags: math, language-agnostic, game-physics, game-development, physics-engine

Pretty much what it says in the title.
Say I have two AABB boxes, and I know both of their velocities, how can I find out the correct pushout vector for them to slide past each other?

Heres what I mean:

```
A_VELOCITY = Vec2(1, 1)
B_VELOCITY = Vec2(0, 0)

 +------+
 |      |
 |   A ++----+
 |     ||    |
 +-----++ B  |
       |     |
       +-----+


How can I get this as a result? (the pushout vector in this case would be Vec2(-1, 0), and the velocity of A would be changed into Vec2(0, 1)):
+------+
|      |
|   A  +-----+
|      |     |
+------+  B  |
       |     |
       +-----+
```

I suspect it has something to do with the dot product and whatnot but to be honest I have no idea how to apply the dot product to well anything...
I hope someone more educated can point me in the right direction / give me the solution. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the initial velocities matter here? Wouldn't the pushout vector be independent of their initial speeds?